# SparkSQL on hive partitioned external table on amazon s3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am planning to use SparkSQL (not pySpark) on top of data in Amazon S3. So I believe I need to create Hive external table and then can use SparkSQL. But S3 data is partitioned and want to have the partitions reflected in Hive external table also.

> What is the best way to manage the hive table on a daily basis. Since
>   , everyday new partitions can be created or old partitions can be
>   overwritten and what to do , so as to keep the Hive external table
>   up-to-date?

Answer (score 0):

Create a intermediate table and load to your hive table with insert overwrite partition on date.

Comment: Thanks Sree . But there will be no data storage(temporary or permanent) in hdfs / hive. Hive will only have the table structure , so spark-SQL can refer to a table like structure .

Comment: So what is that you want to do in Spark?